# File path injection on file upload via form POST

Tags: php, symfony, security

I have a Symfonfy framework set up on an Apache server. Suppose that, on the client side,  I fabricate a request for file upload and POST it to my designated endpoint. What happens if, in this request, the filename field is set to "../../file.png" provided that the mime type is allowed on the server?

Would it be possible to know if path is removed from filename by the containers or the framework as part of processing request? Do I end up with clean version of $request->files->all() on backend that is safe from path injection or do I have to sanitize it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You always have to sanitize your uploaded file name. Never trust what the user sends.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html

*3. A well-known security best practice is to never trust the input provided by users. This also applies to the files uploaded by your visitors.*

Comment: … I gave a link to the official documentation that explain how to upload a file and what best practice is to be followed. *or do I have to sanitize it myself?* < I answered it
The question was not How to upload a file, but whether or not the path given is safe from injection. I think my answer is clear enough

Comment: "A well-known security best practice is to never trust the input provided by users. This also applies to the files uploaded by your visitors. The Uploaded class provides methods to get the original file extension (getExtension()), the original file size (getClientSize()) and the original file name (getClientOriginalName()). However, they are considered not safe because a malicious user could tamper that information. "

It's not clear though whether what ends up in $request->files->all() is original client data or whether Symfony adds a sanitization layer on top of it.